# Installing Python Modules in Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pygame

I downloaded the pygame module (.zip source) from pygame.org but now I am clueless as to how to add this module to python 3 ?

Do I need to copy the downloaded files to any specefic location ?

PS: My platform is Windows 7

Comment: What is you platform?

Comment: It may not work for pygame because of the dependency on a C compiler, but it's a good idea to install `pip` on Windows. See http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html

Answer (score 2):

Pick an appropriate version (msi/exe) from the download page, and double click it like other install program.

Download page: http://pygame.org/download.shtml

Comment: But is there a way to install the source file (.zip) ?

Comment: You can find compile instruction in PyGame wiki pages. But there are incomplete: http://www.pygame.org/wiki/MingW, http://www.pygame.org/wiki/ToolkitCompiler